# Хранение 10^30 записей в БД

Tags: sql, база-данных

Мне нужно как то сохранить 
1 (30 нолей) записей, и осуществить поиск в них за примерно 20 секунд. 
Записи вида (ключ > значение)
Каким образом это дело осуществить то? Я понимаю одной базой тут не обойтись? =)
p.s.
записей: 1 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000

Comment: Вариантов много. Я бы Вам предложил innoDB, в ней не оговорено количество записей, но ключи необходимо хранить в text судя по всему. Если это серверное решение то я бы склонился к тому что просто создавать в определенной папке файлики с именем ключа. тогда доступ к ним всегда будет за 1.

Comment: Зачем комментарий удалили?) Думаю всем интересно, где используются настолько большие базы данных и откуда зеттабайты  памяти...

Comment: А может это какой то госзаказ в контексте пакета яровой и необходимости хранить все логи? Так сказать начинают прощупывать почву

Comment: поиск-то какой? по ключу? посмотрите любое kv-решение на virtual nodes

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Ваше число записывается как 10^30;

Терабайт - Это 10^12. Петабайт - 10^15. Эксабайт - 10^18.

Рассмотрим стандартный телекомовский шкаф высотой 42U. В него можно поместить, при двухсторонней упаковке, 42 дисковые полки высотой 2U

Предположим, что на одной полке стоит 24 диска по 4 Тб, итого, один шкаф хранит 42*24*4= 4032 Тб данных, или 4 Пб.

Вам потребуется всего лишь 10^(30-15)/4=10^15/4 шкафов. Полагая, что шкаф занимает 1 квадратный метр, делаем вывод, что вам понадобится 10^15/4 квадратных метра. Это 10^9 / 4 квадратных километра.

Площадь суши составляет 5*10^8 квадратных километра.

Потребуется еще 1.5 планеты.

Comment: Пожалуй я лучше откажусь от такой бредовой затеи))

Comment: К слову про Землю: можно размещать их в небоскрёбах или под землёй.

Answer (score 14):

Предположим, что ключ и значение компактны, по 8 байт им хватит. Итого, 16 байт на запись.

```
8×2×10^30÷1024÷1024÷1024÷1024 = 1,455191523×10¹⁹ ТиБ
```

Считая нынче одиночный накопитель 3,5" равным 10Тб, а в 4U можно запихать 90 дисков (может чуть больше, это быстрый поиск в гугле), то даже без учёта всякого резервирования вам всё ещё нужны датацентры на 6,5 * 10^16 юнитов. Плюс ошибка конвертирования ТиБ в Тб, которая превращает число в 7,1 * 10^16.

И это только на хранение, только сырых данных и без всякого резервирования. Вам бы сначала выяснить, достаточно ли у человечества ресурсов этот массив куда-то записать и только потом думать, как по нему искать за 20 секунд.